# Adding open/close/leaf images to a gwt tree using Tree.Resources

Tags: gwt, tree

I've been trying to use the Tree.Resources to get the images to for Gwt Tree open state. The following is the resource class that I used.

```
public class TreeImageResource implements Tree.Resources
{

    @Override
    public ImageResource treeClosed()
    {
        return ImageResource.IMAGE_RESOURCE.treeClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public ImageResource treeLeaf()
    {
        return ImageResource.IMAGE_RESOURCE.treeLeaf();
    }

    @Override
    public ImageResource treeOpen()
    {
        return ImageResource.IMAGE_RESOURCE.treeOpen();
    }

}
```

I've tried passing this to the constructor of the tree both in the model and presenter classes for the ui with tree and it is doesn't show the images. What am I missing?

I've created the resource client-bundle as follows

```
public interface ImageResource extends ClientBundle, ClientBundleWithLookup
{
    ImageResource IMAGE_RESOURCE = GWT.create( ImageResource.class );

        @Source("imageresource/treeClosed.gif")
    ImageResource treeClosed();

    @Source("imageresource/treeLeaf.gif")
    ImageResource treeLeaf();

    @Source("imageresource/treeOpen.gif")
    ImageResource treeOpen();
}
```

and the tree is created as follows

```
public class MainPanel extends Composite implements Display
{

  private static MainPanelUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MainPanelUiBinder.class );

  @UiField
  SimplePanel desktopPanel;
  @UiField
  ListBox recentToolsBox;
  @UiField
  Tree recentToolsTree;

  interface MainPanelUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ToolsMainPanel>
  {
  }

  public MainPanel()
  {
    Tree.Resources resources = new TreeImageResource();
    recentToolsTree = new Tree(resources);
    initWidget( uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this) );
    recentToolsTree.setAnimationEnabled( true );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post how you're creating the resources class and the Tree.

Comment: adding the @UiField(provided=true) over the tree declaration worked!.